# Play framework and MySQL, is it possible to define a model with an integer array?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a web-application that should use a model (Play Framwork 2.2.2) with an Integer array to hold one value for each day in a year. Something like this

```
@Entity
public class YearRecord extends Model {

  @Id
  public Integer year;  

  public Integer[] result = new Integer[366];
}
```

I would like to be able to save the model to a MySQL database, a calling application should be able to do something like this

```
YearRecord yr = new YearRecord();
yr.year = 2014;
// assign results here (some values may be left as null)
yr.result[0] = 7;
yr.result[1] = null;
// ...
yr.save();
```

Are saving arrays like this supported by the Play-framework, if so how may it be done and how should the MySQL table be defined? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Are you using an orm? If so, which one? Could you use a `List` instead?

Comment: @manthihetical, I'm using the default ORM, Ebean. For my problem a List would work just as well as Integer[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to have a one-to-many mapping to a `List` of `DayRecord` where `DayRecord` is another entity containing the data you want to store. Something like:

```
@OneToMany
List<DayRecord> dayRecords;

...

@Entity
public class DayRecord extends Model {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private Integer day;  

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private YearRecord yearRecord;

  ...
}
```

Take a look at ebean's cascade [documentation](http://www.avaje.org/cascade.html) as well.